# Download multiple PDF files with Python Playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to automate a PDF download with Playwright in Python from this website: https://www4.trf5.jus.br/diarioeletinternet/paginas/consultas/consultaDiario.faces.

[website print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeD5s.png)

In this example, the script should download the 19 PDFs. But it only downloads 1 and stops.

Here's the script:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright, Playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    nav = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)

    page = nav.new_page(accept_downloads=True) 
    
    page.goto(
    'https://www4.trf5.jus.br/diarioeletinternet/paginas/consultas/consultaDiario.faces;jsessionid=A7EF0E11BE9943A9942B54CE45F7C7F9'
    )

    page.locator("[name='frmVisao:orgao']").select_option('SeçãoJudiciária do Sergipe')
    page.locator("[name='frmVisao:edicao']").select_option('Administrativo')
    page.locator("[name='frmVisao:periodo']").select_option('2021')
    page.wait_for_function("""
        document
          .querySelectorAll('[id="frmVisao:meses"] option')
          .length > 11
    """)
    page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="frmVisao:meses"]').select_option('03')
    page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="frmVisao:j_id48"]').click()
    page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="frmPesquisa:quantidadeRegistros"]').select_option('50')
    rows = page.query_selector_all(".rich-table tbody tr td:nth-child(4)")

    for row in rows:
        with page.expect_download() as download_info:
            row.click()
        
        download = download_info.value
        download.save_as(download.suggested_filename)
    
    page.close()
    nav.close()
```

Where's the error?

Comment: Good question, as with your [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78177245/using-python-playwright-to-select-a-value-from-a-select-dropdown), although there are some indentation syntax errors I suggest [edit]ing to fix if you have a minute. Thanks.

Comment: It may be time to put some `print()` lines in the code. Like a `print(download.suggested_filename)` could tell multiple things: if it prints more than one filename, and if they happen to be the same (so files are overwriting each other).

Comment: I thougth this my be the problem, so i add this line: `download.save_as('Diario{}.pdf'.format(x)) 
x += 1`
But the dont work. Im get this error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bosco\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\playwright\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    row.click()" ...